# How can i add dependencies between actions with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Consider the code below

App.js:

```
function user_getUser() {
  return dispatch => {
     dispatch({ type: "GET_USER" })
  }
}

function user_getCustomer() {
  return dispatch => {
     dispatch({ type: "GET_CUSTOMER" })
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>Hello world !</div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {} 
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    getUser: () => dispatch(user_getUser()),
    getCustomer: () => dispatch(user_getCustomer()),
  }
}

ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I simplified the code but normally getUser() and getCustomer() get JSON objects from an api. I would like to execute getCustomer() when the api responsed to getUser().
Is it possible?

PS: I'm a beginner with reactJS so be indulgent

Comment: This is a job for a middleware like [redux thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)

Comment: +1 to using Redux Thunk. Follow the documentation. In fact ... if you're a beginner i'd recommend starting from beginning to end with a couple of React tutorials then build your own UI before even touching Redux. If you *have* to use Redux go through the full egghead.io tut by Dan Abramov.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk). It will let you run async code and then you could chain your functions. Another nice thing that you could do with it is check your store's state in the actions in case you need for example something from the store AFTER the first call has been completed.

Side note - Maybe you could refactor the server side to bring you both pieces of data together and then you could do it in 1 API call without having to wait until 1 finishes and then start the next.

2nd Side Note - If the calls are not necessarily dependent on each other, maybe use something like Promise.all?

```
Promise.all([user_getUser(), user_getCustomer()]
.then(([user, customer]) => { 
   dispatch(...) 
});
```

Comment: Nice ! It's ok. Thanks